# Fit WebView content into screen - Android

Tags: android, android-webview

In Motorola Droid Mini(Kitkat) the webview content is not fitting the screen. In all other devices its working fine. I am using following settings for my webview. Is I am missing anything or how can I make it to fit the screen. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
    web.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    web.setSaveEnabled(true);
    web.setInitialScale(1);
    web.setBackgroundColor(0);
    WebSettings myWebSettings = web.getSettings();
    myWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    myWebSettings.setUserAgentString("android");
    myWebSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    myWebSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    myWebSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

**EDIT:**
My webview XML is

```
    <WebView
    and roid:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: Have you given width and height of webview in xml to match_parent?

Comment: webview content like Image either small/large than screen. If I want to make it fit to screen like Fill_parent is it possible?

Comment: Two screenshots will be helpful

Comment: I used styling which we use for responsive websites, In my case HTML code is available to me So I added it. It will fit content to device width.